# Getting the members with values in SerializationInfo

Tags: c#, serialization

Is there a way to know which members were added to an instance of `SerializationInfo` in the `GetDataObject` method of a `ISerializable` object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes: `foreach`

```
foreach(SerializationEntry entry in info) {...}
```

You would be forgiven for not noticing this, as it doesn't implement and `IEnumerable` API, but: `foreach` does not require that it does :)

See MSDN for what this provides per item: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationentry(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Interesting! Do you have any idea why it doesn't implement `IEnumerable` though? And why it returns a concrete `SerializationInfoEnumerator` instead of an `IEnumerator`? This seems like an odd choice..

Comment: @dcastro if I had to guess, the lack of IEnumerable is an oversight that never got corrected because it isn't necessary. The choice of a custom iterator is not all that uncommon, especially in code that predates generics, with the intent being avoiding boxing and allocations by using a struct to represent state. Even in generic code it isn't uncommon: List-of-T has a custom iterator, for example.

Comment: Yeah, `List<T>` also returns its own custom iterator, to implement the "throw exception if list has changed" mechanism. But it still returns the iterator disguised as an interface. But I agree that it's probably to avoid boxing - I just noticed [`SerializationInfoEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfoenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) has two `Current` properties, one explicitly implemented that returns an `object`, and another that returns a `SerializationEntry`.

Comment: @dcastrono and no; it can do the "throw" stuff without a publicly visible custom iterator type, and no: it does not hide it behind an interface - it is explicitly custom: a `List<T>.Enumerator` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765(v=vs.110).aspx). The only reason to to this is to avoid allocations, which is worthwhile since `List<T>` is so common. A shame that LINQ doesn't use it. Tempting to write a  `List<T>`-LINQ library :)

Comment: I completely missed that... this may be getting a little off-topic, but: since `List<T>` does not predate generics... wouldn't returning a non-custom, generic `IEnumerator<T>` also avoid allocations?

Comment: @dcastro no, returning something as IEnumerable-of-T / IEnumerator-of-T will always involve an allocation, since a struct is boxed when treated as an interface (with the exception of "constrained", but that doesn't apply here)

Comment: Ohh! I thought we were talking about allocation of the *items*, not the iterator! I see now! So, `SerializationInfo` saves on allocating items by having a custom iterator with a `SerializationEntry Current` property, and *also* saves on allocating the iterator by returning the iterator itself, not as an interface. `List<T>` wouldn't need any of these to prevent allocating items, since it could simply use yield and return an `IEnumerator<T>`, but it still implements a custom iterator to prevent allocating it.

Comment: @dcastro exactly: zero allocation: the iterator is a struct and each iterated item is a struct, or (in the case of the list) is some object or value that already existed

Comment: We weren't on the same page :P Also, now your comment about LINQ not using the list's custom iterator makes perfect sense to me!

Comment: +1 Unfortunately, this wasn't refactored to use a generic in dotnet core 3.1, so, while an old answer about dotnet Framework, it helped me with code in 2020.

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop they tried very hard to not include it at all (a decision would have supported 100% - see https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html), so it isn't surprising that there weren't any feature additions.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm not using BinaryFormatter (from your link) at all. I'm using SerializationInfo as part of exception serialization into json for serilog. It's part of one of the base constructors for Exception if you want it to serialize properly, especially since I have additional properties on a custom exception that I would like to make it to ELK.

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop either way, that type is fundamentally part of that feature set - so: don't expect API additions

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear [to be a "contains"](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/625333-why-there-no-contains-exists-serializationinfo) method.  There is a [GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.getenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that you can use to loop through it.  But Marc's foreach suggestion is the better one :)

Comment: To most useful definitions, `GetEnumerator()` *is* `foreach` - they are essentially synonymous

Comment: For full context, `foreach(var item in obj) { /* your code */ }` is *basically*: `using(var iter = obj.GetEnumerator()) { while (iter.MoveNext()) { var item = iter.Current; /* your code */ }}`